# SWT: Table with copy/paste functions

Tags: java, swt

This maybe a really silly question but I just could not find the answer anywhere, is there any way for the user to be able to highlight rows in an SWT Table and either <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>right-click</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy the values?

I would specifically like to be able to copy into an excel sheet.

This is how I create the table,

```
Table aTable = new Table(parent, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER
                | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
aTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
aTable.setLinesVisible(true);

aTable.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

I have seen information about this using a JTable but nothing with an SWT. If JTable is my only option, then what would be the dis/advantages of using either?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily code it.

Add a key listener to your table and listen for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keys. When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is hit, get the selection from the table, extract text from each of the TableItems and form a tab-separated-fields/newline-separated-rows String containing your data. Then just put it into clipboard (see `org.eclipse.swt.dnd.Clipboard#setContents`, use TextTransfer data type).

That is it - your result will be pasteable into Excel.

Comment: But what about in the case of the mouse context menu? (when you right-click)

Comment: Well, you do the exact same thing, the only difference is, you also add a context menu to your table, add the menu item for Copy, and on selection of that menu item, you do exactly what you did in the previous listener...

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is good, but since developers prefer code snippets over text I'd answer the question this way:

```
aTable.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.stateMask == SWT.CTRL && (e.keyCode == 'c' || e.keyCode == 'C')) {
            Clipboard clipboard = new Clipboard(Display.getDefault());
            clipboard.setContents(new Object[] { getTextFromSelectedRows() }, new Transfer[] { TextTransfer.getInstance() });
            clipboard.dispose();
        }
    }
});
```

Then just implement a `getTextFromSelectedRows()`-Method that - based on the table selection - returns the `String` that should be added to the clipboard.